# "expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '+=' token" error in c code

Tags: android, c++, c, gcc, dalvik

I have following code snippet from the dalvikvm source code.
While building I am getting following error,

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '+=' token
```

in the code snippet,

```
    #ifdef CHECK_BRANCH_OFFSETS                                                     
# define ADJUST_PC(_offset) do {                                                \
        int myoff = _offset;        /* deref only once */                       \
        if (pc + myoff < curMethod->insns ||                                    \
            pc + myoff >= curMethod->insns + dvmGetMethodInsnsSize(curMethod))  \
        {                                                                       \
            char* desc;                                                         \
            desc = dexProtoCopyMethodDescriptor(&curMethod->prototype);         \
            LOGE("Invalid branch %d at 0x%04x in %s.%s %s\n",                   \
                myoff, (int) (pc - curMethod->insns),                           \
                curMethod->clazz->descriptor, curMethod->name, desc);           \
            free(desc);                                                         \
            dvmAbort();                                                         \
        }                                                                       \
        pc += myoff;                                                            \
        EXPORT_EXTRA_PC();                                                      \
    } while (false)
#else
# define ADJUST_PC(_offset) do {                                                \                                   
        pc += _offset;                                                          \
        EXPORT_EXTRA_PC();                                                      \
    } while (false)
#endif
```

The error is showing for `pc +=_offset;` line.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what pc and _offset are when ADJUST_PC() is instantiated.

Comment: That's just a macro definition.  Check the context where it's actually failing and figure out how `pc` is defined at that point.  If you're compiling `dalvik/vm/mterp/out/InterpC-portable.cpp`, it's declared at the top of `dvmInterpretPortable`.  One trick: use "make showcommands" to get the full command line, then execute it manually, adding `-save-temps`.  That'll get you a `.i` file, which has the preprocessor symbols expanded.

Comment: If that's an exact copy of your code, then it's probably because you've got whitespace after the backslash on the previous line. The backslash has to be the very last character on the line to continue the macro definition into the next line.

Comment: @fadden very helpful information. Thanks.

Comment: @fadden can you have a look on my latest question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416608/compilin-error-fields-must-have-a-constant-size-variable-length-array-in-stru